# TreeViewItem MouseDoubleClick not proving correct sender in event handler

Tags: wpf

I have a treeview with some nodes along with some subnodes.In those subnodes, I have attached an event handler for MouseDoubleClick.

But in the event handler, the sender parameter is referring to the the parent node, not the subnode where I am double clicking.

```
private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string[] drives = System.Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
    foreach (string drive in drives)
    {
        TreeViewItem node = new TreeViewItem(){Header=drive,Tag=drive};
        TreeViewFolders.Items.Add(node);
        node.MouseDoubleClick+=new MouseButtonEventHandler(rootUI_MouseDoubleClick);
    }
}

void rootUI_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem node = sender as TreeViewItem;
    node.Items.Clear();
    string folder = ((TreeViewFolders.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem).Tag) as string;

        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = new DirectoryInfo(folder).GetDirectories();
            foreach (DirectoryInfo sd in subDirectories)
            {
                TreeViewItem subnode = new TreeViewItem() { Header = sd.Name,Tag=sd.FullName};
                node.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(rootUI_MouseDoubleClick);
                node.Items.Add(subnode);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

At the topmost level, there are logical drives and then subfolders and so on.
Whesn I click the subnode(the folders in logical drives), the sender parameter is still the local drives, not the particular subnode.

It works OK when I use SelectedItem instead of sender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code adds another double-click handler to the same node that the double-click handler fired on.  Perhaps you meant to add a handler for a double-click on the sub-node?

Comment: you can see that I am attaching the event handler for the newly created nodes also.CODE:          foreach (DirectoryInfo sd in subDirectories)             {                 TreeViewItem subnode = new TreeViewItem() { Header = sd.Name,Tag=sd.FullName};                 node.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(rootUI_MouseDoubleClick);                 node.Items.Add(subnode);             }

Comment: Rick, It was my mistake,I corrected the code to add the event handler to subnode.By this way I get the correct sender but after it, the event also fires for the parent node which clears the sub nodes.Can you correct me.

Comment: @Akshay: Due to the way that `Control.MouseDoubleClick` works, it fires all the way up the `TreeViewItem` parent chain.  To prevent this, you can add a `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` handler and check `sender == e.Source && e.ClickCount == 2` to detect only double-clicks on the item that was double-clicked.

Comment: But from what the books say, the usual way to supress an event from bubbling is to set e.Handled to true and I am doing this in my code.Why is it not working.

Comment: As it happens, `Control.MouseDoubleClick` is a direct routed event so it only goes to the object it is raised on so it doesn't matter if you handle it because it doesn't bubble.  In other words, if `MouseDoubleClick` occurs on two or more `TreeViewItem` controls, it isn't because of bubbling.  The reason is that `MouseDoubleClick` is a synthetic event based on `MouseLeftButtonDown` which **does** bubble and no one is handling it.